# Hot to make a dynamic lightning:inputfield required

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, required-field, lightning-inputfield, dynamic-binding

I have a fieldset which I get from serverside and load on clientside I am adding the required parameter to the field but my component does not alert on required.  I added the values behind the fields and these have the correct value. What am I missing?

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.fields}" var="field" >
            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.inputModeBool == true? true: false}">
                <lightning:inputField fieldName="{!field.fieldPath}"  required="{!field.required}"/>{!field.required}
            </aura:if>
            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.inputModeBool != true? true: false}">
                <lightning:layout >
                    <lightning:layoutitem size="10">
                        <lightning:outputField fieldName="{!field.fieldPath}"/>
                    </lightning:layoutitem>
                    <lightning:layoutitem size="2">
                        <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:edit" variant="bare"
                                              alternativeText="edit"
                                              onclick="{!c.handleToggle}"/>
                    </lightning:layoutitem>
                </lightning:layout>
            </aura:if>
        </aura:iteration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [specification](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:inputField/specification) of `lightning:inputField` does not specify required as an attribute. The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:inputField/documentation) tab mentions the following:

> To persist requiredness on a field, select the Required checkbox when defining the custom field in Setup. A required field is displayed with a red asterisk next to the field label. An error message is displayed below a required field if you try to submit the form before entering a value.

So it seems, in order to use the lightning:inputField component, either the field has to be required at the schema level or you would have to implement the validation in your javascript controller.

Comment: The fields are set as required in setup in this case on field level and in the fieldset.